# How to convert a non serializable object to byte array?

Tags: java, serialization

I'm trying to use javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(byte[]) method to encrypt an object. But, for security reasons, the object cannot be serializable.
So, how to convert the object to byte array without serialization?

**--update**

is using serialization the only way to use this Cipher method? Because as I know important data should not be serializable.

Comment: And I guess equally importantly... convert it back again.

Comment: You want to serialize an object which "For security reason, the object cannot be serializable" Are you aware that serializable is used for converting the the object to a byte[]?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey please, see my update

Comment: @Tom Brito Just out of curiosity, why shouldn't important data be serializable?  I hadn't heard of this.

Comment: @Bill K
http://java.sun.com/security/seccodeguide.html
Guideline 5-1 Avoid serialization for security-sensitive classes

Comment: @Tom Brito--Oh, I see.  If you are implementing a security manager of your own that makes sense!  I was wondering how avoiding serialization was helpful when you can just reflect into any class, but if you're going so far as to override the SecurityManager than this is a very sane step--otherwise it's utterly pointless of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,
instead of use a getByteArray() to call Cipher.doFinal(), I'll use Cipher.doFinal() inside the class, with a getEncryptedByteArray() method; so I serialize the data inside the class without making the class itself serializable, and the return result will be encrypted.
Any objection to this approach will be considered.. :)

Answer (score 4):

I used com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.

```
  private static byte[] serialize(Object obj) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    mapper.writeValue(os, obj);

    return os.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: how we can deserialize that object.

Comment: Throws InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer

Answer (score 0):

You just serialize each of it's components.  Recurse.  Eventually you end up with native objects that you can serialize.

If you implement this by implementing java's serialization methods, java will ensure that you do not serialize any object twice and will take care of references for you.

In short, make the object serializable.

Comment: same as @Randy Simon's answer, see the comments

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple example of serializing a class to a byte array.

```
public Class Foo {

    private boolean isHappy;
    private short happyCount;
    private Bar bar;

    public byte[] serializeData () throws IOException
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream( stream );

        out.writeBoolean(isHappy);
        out.writeShort( slope );

        // Serialize bar which will just append to this byte stream
        bar.doSerializeData(out);

        // Return the serialized object.
        byte[] data = stream.toByteArray();

        // Clean up.
        stream.close();

        return data;
    }
}
```

Of course, a lot of the details in your case depend on your class structure but hopefully this gets you pointed in the right direction.

To deserialize you just need to reverse the above.

Comment: The same security considerations that dictated that the class should not be Serializable should dictate that this method not be written.

Answer (score -1):

java.beans.XMLEncoder/Decoder.

Comment: Of course. Nothing you can do about that. It exists whether you like it or not, so therefore the class in question is insecure if it is XMLEncodable.

What I think you need is a method *in the class* that delivers a SealedObject and that uses private member data to construct it.