# object array to inputstream

Tags: java, inputstream

I have an array of person class

```
Class Person
{}
```

Could anyone please help me to convert `Person[]` array to inputstream or to a byteStream?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [serialization explained](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization)

Comment: Thanks for reply...Basically I have used Person class as example but I have a class that comes with a jar and it is not serializable. In this case I cannot go ahead with the serialization.

Comment: If you can't use serialization, then this question should be rephrased. And yes, it has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239280/which-is-the-best-alternative-for-java-serialization

Comment: Your question is meaningless. If your class isn't serializable, you can't serialize it, so there is nothing you can 'convert it ... to input stream or byte stream' *from.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to write (serialise) your objects to streams, your class should implement  [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface. In most cases you don't need to do anything except for adding the "implements Serializable" clause in your class definition:

```
class Person implements Serializable {
// your class's fields and methods
}
```

Then, of course, you are not writing to the *input* stream, but to an *output* stream:

```
Person p = new Person();
// some more code here...
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("persons.txt"); // open file as a stream
os.write(person); // write person object to the stream
os.close(); // close the stream
```

To convert to a byte array you will have to use serialization still:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
baos.write(person);
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Thanks Maksimov, but I dont want to write my object to a file rather I want a byte array also I cant add serializable to it since it is packaged in a jar file.

Comment: @Ritesh I've updated the answer to cover byte array case, but for cases when the object is not serializable, you'll have to workaround this. See this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563340/how-to-convert-a-non-serializable-object-to-byte-array